# OTI Copni device Java Card Applet install fails

Tags: authentication, applet, installation, javacard

I have an OTI Copni device and I need to install a `.cap` file to this Copni device. So I have JCOP tools with Eclipse and I try to upload and install. It then gives this the indicated error. I presume this is happening because of a failed authentication.

```
cm>  /term "winscard:4|SCM Microsystems Inc. SDI011G Contactless Reader 0"
--Opening terminal
>  /card -a a000000003000000 -c com.ibm.jc.CardManager
resetCard with timeout: 0 (ms)
--Waiting for card...
ATR=3B 88 80 01 00 73 C8 40 00 00 90 00 62             ;....s.@....b
ATR: T=0, T=1, Hist=0073C84000009000
 => 00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00          ..............
 (21592 usec)
 <= 6F 65 84 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 A5 59 9F 65    oe...........Y.e
    01 FF 9F 6E 06 47 91 20 17 3F 00 73 4A 06 07 2A    ...n.G. .?.sJ..*
    86 48 86 FC 6B 01 60 0C 06 0A 2A 86 48 86 FC 6B    .H..k.`...*.H..k
    02 02 01 01 63 09 06 07 2A 86 48 86 FC 6B 03 64    ....c...*.H..k.d
    0B 06 09 2A 86 48 86 FC 6B 04 02 15 65 0B 06 09    ...*.H..k...e...
    2B 85 10 86 48 64 02 01 03 66 0C 06 0A 2B 06 01    +...Hd...f...+..
    04 01 2A 02 6E 01 02 90 00                         ..*.n....
Status: No Error
cm>  set-key 255/1/DES-ECB/404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f 255/2/DES-ECB/404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f 255/3/DES-ECB/404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f
cm>  init-update 255
 => 80 50 00 00 08 C2 3F 4B C4 BE B6 E5 58 00          .P....?K....X.
 (43622 usec)
 <= 00 00 32 98 00 09 30 97 06 25 01 02 00 10 68 6C    ..2...0..%....hl
    E3 CA 2C 2B 4D 2C 4B 0D 0E 62 5F 8C 90 00          ..,+M,K..b_...
Status: No Error
cm>  ext-auth plain
 => 84 82 00 00 10 EB FC 66 BC FA 30 91 58 5B 51 FA    .......f..0.X[Q.
    0C 46 D7 43 C9                                     .F.C.
 (12557 usec)
 <= 69 85                                              i.
Status: Conditions of use not satisfied
jcshell: Error code: 6985 (Conditions of use not satisfied)
jcshell: Wrong response APDU: 6985
Unexpected error; aborting execution
```

Can someone tell me how to upload a `.cap` file to this device?

Answer (score 0):

Try `ext-auth mac` instead, the smart card is probably in the state OP_SECURE, which means that at minimal command MAC is required.

Answer (score 0):

As JCOP tools is not publicly available nor open source, I'd suggest you try a publicly available piece of software instead:

https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatform#globalplatform-from-openkms

(as the name of the github repository implies this is self-promotion)